# how to convert functional component to class component?

Tags: reactjs

i am new to React.js i am trying to convert funbctional component to class component can anyone help me ?
here is my code i want to convert that code which is in functional componetn to class component

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import  {DateRangePicker}  from 'react-date-range';
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; // main style file
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'; // theme css file
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';
import { useState } from 'react';
function App(){
const [state, setState] = useState([
  {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
    key: 'selection'
  }
]);
return(
<DateRangePicker
  onChange={item => setState([item.selection])}
  showSelectionPreview={true}
  moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
  months={2}
  ranges={state}
  direction="horizontal"
/>
);
}
```

can anyone help me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** To fix **"TypeError: ranges.findIndex is not a function"** error, you should put your **selectionRange** in array to the prop.

Like this:
`ranges={ [ this.state.selectionRange ] }`

Not like this: `ranges={ this.state.selectionRange }`

For more info, check the example here: [react-date-range - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range)

And I think you should check here too: [Function and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

```
import React from "react";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-date-range";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main style file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file
import { addDays } from "date-fns";

class ComponentName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectionRange: {
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
        key: "selection"
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DateRangePicker
        onChange={(item) => this.setState({selectionRange: item.selection})}
        showSelectionPreview={true}
        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
        months={2}
        ranges={[this.state.selectionRange]}
        direction="horizontal"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response sir ... but sir by doing that i am getting this error "TypeError: ranges.findIndex is not a function"

Comment: sir error i removed but  date is not slected when i tried to slect another date

Comment: Ups, my fault, update onChange prop like this: onChange={(item) => this.setState({selectionRange: item.selection})}

Comment: thanks alot sir .... i was unable to solve that one from the past 1 hour thanks sir means alot

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-date-range';
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; // main style file
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'; // theme css file
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';

class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
    key: 'selection'
  };
  
  handleDateSelect = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      ...item
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { startDate, endDate, key } = this.state;

    return (
      <DateRangePicker
        onChange={item => this.handleDateSelect(item)}
        showSelectionPreview={true}
        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
        months={2}
        ranges={{
          startDate,
          endDate,
          key
        }}
        direction="horizontal"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks for your response sir ... but sir by doing that i am getting this error "TypeError: ranges.findIndex is not a function"

Comment: Seems that `ranges` should be an array. Not an object